# Can't rename files on desktop via hotkey in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04

In previous versions of Ubuntu (16.04, 18.04) I renamed the files on the desktop using the F2 hotkey. But in Ubuntu 20.04 I can't do this. This is possible only by right-clicking mouse on the file and selecting the "Rename" option that is very inconvenient. How to make the system allow me to rename desktop files using a hotkey?

I also tried to find something on Google, but I did not find anything useful.

But in nautilus I can rename file using hotkey.